# Accessing files on mssql filestore through UNC path is causing delay c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, filestream, unc, file-storage

I am experiencing some strange behaviour from my code which i am using to stream files to my clients. 
I have a mssql server which acts as a filestore, with files that is accessed via an UNC path.

On my webserver i have some .net code running that handles streaming the files (in this case pictures and thumbnails) to my clients.

My code works, but i am experiencing a constant delay of ~12 sec on the initial file request. When i have made the initial request it is as the server wakes up and suddenly becomes responsive only to fall back to the same behaviour some time after.

At first i thought it was my code, but from what i can see on the server activity log there is no ressource intensive code going on. My theory is that at each call to the server the path must first be mounted and that is what causes the delay. It will then unmount some time after and will have to remount.

For reference i am posting my code (maybe i just cannot see the problem):

```
public async static Task StreamFileAsync(HttpContext context, FileInfo fileInfo)
{
        //This controls how many bytes to read at a time and send to the client
        int bytesToRead = 512 * 1024; // 512KB

        // Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];

        // Clear the current response content/headers
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();

        //Indicate the type of data being sent
        context.Response.ContentType = FileTools.GetMimeType(fileInfo.Extension);

        //Name the file
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" + fileInfo.Name + "\"");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());

        // Open the file
        using (var stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
        {
            // The number of bytes read
            int length;
            do
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected
                if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read data into the buffer
                    length = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                    // and write it out to the response's output stream
                    await context.Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, length);

                    try
                    {
                        // Flush the data
                        context.Response.Flush();
                    }
                    catch (HttpException)
                    {
                        // Cancel the download if a HttpException happens
                        // (ie. the client has disconnected by we tried to send some data)
                        length = -1;
                    }

                    //Clear the buffer
                    buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
                }
                else
                {
                    // Cancel the download if client has disconnected
                    length = -1;
                }
            } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
        }

        // Tell the response not to send any more content to the client
        context.Response.SuppressContent = true;

        // Tell the application to skip to the EndRequest event in the HTTP pipeline
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

If anyone could shed some light over this problem i would be very grateful!

Comment: Maybe try using sysinternals process explorer to see what's going on while you're experiencing the delay.  It's free.

Comment: Could it be misconfigured DNS server? Resolving your server name incorrectly initially, getting timeout and then falling back to correct address?

Comment: I will try process explorer to try and figure out what is wrong. I do not thing it is the DNS as i am using the ip directly.